# Redux action creators invoke one inside another

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I am using [ducks](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux) with Redux, but that should be irrelevant to the question. I have a couple of action creators in the same file and I want to invoke one from within the other (hopefully without having to double dispatch for every CASE in the SWITCH below):

```
...
export function closeAuthDialogs() {
  return {type: CLOSE_AUTH_DIALOGS}
}

export function openDialog(dialog) {
  // close any open dialogs
  dispatch => {dispatch(closeAuthDialogs())} // <--THIS DOES NOT GET CALLED!!!
  //open the one we need
  switch (dialog) {
    case 'login':
      return {type: OPEN_LOGIN}
    case 'register':
      return {type: OPEN_REGISTER}
    case 'forgot':
      return {type: OPEN_FORGOT}
    case 'change':
      return {type: OPEN_CHANGE}
    case 'profile':
      return {type: OPEN_PROFILE}
    default:
      return;
  }
}
...
```

The opens work fine, but the close function never gets fired. Is there a way to invoke the close function from within the open function without double dispatching for each CASE in the SWITCH of the open function?

By double dispatching I mean something like...

```
return dispatch => {
  dispatch({type: CLOSE_AUTH_DIALOGS})
  dispatch({type: OPEN_SOME_DIALOG)}
}
```

If possible, I'd like to only invoke the close once and then return the specified open.

TIA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a middleware like [redux-thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk). Installation instructions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk#installation) but basically you need to apply it when you're setting up your store:

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

This will allow you to return a function from an action. Something like this should do it:

```
export function openDialog(dialog) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(closeAuthDialogs());
    switch (dialog) {
      case 'login':
        return dispatch({type: OPEN_LOGIN})
      case 'register':
        return dispatch({type: OPEN_REGISTER})
      case 'forgot':
        return dispatch({type: OPEN_FORGOT})
      case 'change':
        return dispatch({type: OPEN_CHANGE})
      case 'profile':
        return dispatch({type: OPEN_PROFILE})
      default:
        return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have the think middleware. Was just missing the return on the close dispatch and wrapping them all in it.

Comment: Yeah, if you use thunk, return values from the inner function have no effect—you have to `dispatch` explicitly now that you have it as an argument.